# Powershell nested variables

Tags: powershell

Soo trying to do something like the following

$Computers = Get-Content .\~test.txt

```
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
     $computer.Attempts += 1
     $computer.result = Successful
}
```

++ EDIT ++
The output i want is

```
$MyComputerName.Attempt += 1
$MyComputerName.result
```

So that each computer will have its own name creating a basic table within the script so that it doesn't have to keep reading some information from a text file.

where $computer is the computer name in the text file. I am trying to do this to create a faster method of checking valuables.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. Please explain in more a detail what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright eventually got this thing figured out and was as follows. Import-CSV is a great tool for creating a new object for each line.

```
$Computers = @(Import-CSV .\Computers.txt)

ForEach ($Computer IN $Computers) {
    Write-host $Computer.Name
    Write-Host $Computer.IP
    Write-Host $Computer.Other
}
```

Computers.txt:

```
52123-9421,123.123.123.123,yea
HELLBOMBS-PC,123.123.123.123,yea
52123-942dv,123.123.123.123,yea
52123-942RM,123.123.123.123,yea
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following you, you want to create new object for each computer:

```
$Computers = Get-Content .\~test.txt

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $Computer 
        Attempts = 1
        Result = 'Successful'
    }
}
```

Comment: so how would i call that object, say if i wanted to load the information from it. Lets say later in the script i wanted to check if $Computer.result = successful?

Comment: Assign the foreach loop to a variable and use array indexing to get it (in case of multiple objects_. Another way would be to create a hashtable out of it and then use the hashtable 'Key' name to refer to the object.